# How 8021q tagged frame making in NDIS NET_BUFFER LIST of Ethernet field?

Tags: filter, ethernet, ndis, wifi, vlan

I am testing my virtual driver to get HLK certification. In HLK, they have 2c_priority test which will check the sending of 802.1 p tagged packet.

Initially i am not supporting 802.1p . In order to support 802.1p , I added `NDIS_MAC_OPTION_8021P_PRIORITY` and `NDIS_MAC_OPTION_8021Q_VLAN` options in `OID_GEN_MAC_OPTIONS`OID query.

During the HLK Test , I tracked all the NetBufferList for finding the 802.1p tag frame with

```
NDIS_NET_BUFFER_LIST_8021Q_INFO  NdisPacket8021qInfo;
NdisPacket8021qInfo.Value = NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO(NetBufferList, Ieee8021QNetBufferListInfo);
```

using this , i can see

```
NdisPacket8021qInfo.TagHeader.VlanId = 0 ;
NdisPacket8021qInfo.TagHeader.UserPriority = 5
```

etc..

I can see `NdisPacket8021qInfo.TagHeader.UserPriority` values changing like 5 , 1, 6 , 4 etc..

Now i check my receive end to check whether the Netbufferlist have same Priority . But i didn't see any values .

**My doubts are :**

- I didn't insert this 802.1p tag inside Ethernet field during
  sendNetBufferList function . Will HLK itself add this tag inside
  Ethernet field ? or should i manually add to the Ethernet field of NetBufferList  ?
- Is this why i can't see 802.1p packets during receive process ? But
  why i can't see any NDIS_NET_BUFFER_LIST_8021Q_INFO values of NetBufferList   during receive process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miniport driver must insert an 802.1p tag inside the actual packet payload during Tx.  Since you're building a virtual driver, you have 2 options:

- Your driver can edit the Ethernet frame itself, to manually insert the 802.1p field.  In effect, you'll insert 4 bytes after the 14-byte Ethernet header (although beware of SNAP-framing).
- Don't edit the Ethernet frame.  Instead, pass the 802.1p information inside whatever metadata you give to the other end of your virtual connection.  You presumably already pass metadata that includes the packet length -- if it's possible to add additional metadata, you can add another field for the 802.1p data.

Once you do one of the above, you then need to do the opposite on the Rx side.  Either strip the 802.1p header from the packet payload, or read the 802.1p info from your metadata.  Then put the 802.1p info into the Rx NBL.

Comment: Here in My case , HLK will add the tags when he send packets . So i don't want add any suffs to add inside netbufferlist . Now i can see whenever i query `NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO(netbufferlist,Ieee8021QNetBufferListInfo)` , i can see that priority values . But when i am receiving packets , i just check same process whether this priority present or not in the packet But i got zero values when  i use `NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO` . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your miniport driver's responsibility is to somehow ensure the 802.1p tags get carried along with each transmitted packet.  When your miniport driver indicates a receive, it should write an 802.1p value into the NBL.

Comment: But my miniport driver act like a dummy . I have a filter driver over each physical adapter . So can i handle this 802.1p scenario on filter driver send packet function ?

Comment: And i have another doubt . When HLK NdisTester send packets , will it add header to the packet directly by itself or only set Ieee8021QNetBufferListInf‌​o in NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO ?

Comment: At the end of the day, you've written a driver that moves packets from somewhere to somewhere else.  Along with those packets, you need to include the 802.1p metadata.  This is always inside the Ieee8021QNetBufferListInfo.

Comment: yeah . thanks for your information . Finally i stuffed 802.1p header to Ethernet frame  and i stripped these header on receive side . Using the header i updated the Ieee8021QNetBufferListInfo . it's working now .